# Dynamics CRM 2016 tracking emails correctly but Outlook showing as not tracked.

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, office365

We're using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 with Outlook (Office 365). All very new so we have the latest versions of each. Users track emails from Outlook using the 'Set Regarding' function. The tracking is working fine, with 1 major exception. When someone replies to a tracked email, the reply is tracked correctly in CRM, however in the Outlook client there is nothing to show the email is tracked. I.e. normally you would expect to see the little CRM icon (green and blue people), and also a CRM at the footer of the email with details about the tracking. Instead it just looks like a normal email, notwithstanding that it is indeed tracked in CRM. The original tracked email shows correctly (with the green and blue icon and the CRM footer). It's just the replies that are not appearing correctly.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are two tracking methods for Dynamics CRM: automatic tracking and manual tracking.
When an email is tracked by the automatic tracking, the UI in CRM for Outlook (Outlook add-in) will not reflect that.
We are planning to improve this when using the new CRM App for Outlook (office app).

Ben